# Adding a local admin account to a device using a batch script and csv

Tags: loops, batch-file, csv, cmd

I'm stuck in a bit of a pickle and i am wondering if someone could help. I work in a school in which at the beginning of the year, we assign new laptops to a new year level.

What i need to do is give each student local admin rights to a laptop that has been assigned to them.

I currently have a csv file which has two columns. One with the students username, the second with the laptops device name on the server.

```
eg. jdoe1,device001
    jdoe2,device002
```

What i would like to do is automate adding the local admin account of each device by having the the batch script pull the names on each row and adding them as the local admin of the device that is assigned.

```
eg. script finds the username jdoe1, then sees device001. 
    It then creates a local account called jdoe1 
    (which is pulled from the active directory on our server) 
    on the laptop device001.
    The script then moves to the next row and starts the process again.
```

This is what i have so far. This will pull the name and device name and do what is neded but if there are multiple rows of names it will only process the last row and i need it to do each row individually. The script also changes the description of the device to include the students username and the device name.

(please note this is messy as i am very new to batch scripting)

```
@echo.
@echo The following script will assign a student to a laptop, giving the student
@echo Administration rights to the laptop and set the laptop description.
@echo.
@echo.
@echo.
@pause
cls
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%a in (data.csv) DO (
@set user=%%a
@set LaptopID=%%b
)
@set desc= CFS - Mobile Student - %LaptopID% - %user%
@echo.
@echo Please enter Admin Username
@set /p adminusr=
cls
@echo.
@echo Please enter Admin Password (make sure noone is looking as password is displayed)
@set /p adminpw=
cls
@echo.
@echo Now creating local admin account for %user% on %LaptopID%
@echo.
@echo Description: %desc%
@echo.
@pause
@***\psexec \\%LaptopID% -u ***\%adminusr% -p %adminpw% -n 20 -e net localgroup Administrators "***\%user%" /add
@***\psexec \\%LaptopID% -u ***\%adminusr% -p %adminpw% -n 20 -e net config server /srvcomment:"%desc%"
@pause
```

The *** is replaced as needed. For each new username i need to be able to view the username and pc it is being assigned to, so i can confirm the details (a requirement by the head of the IT department)

Can this be done?? please help!!

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo.
echo The following script will assign a student to a laptop, giving the student
echo Administration rights to the laptop and set the laptop description.
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
cls
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%a in (data.csv) DO (
set user=%%a
set LaptopID=%%b
set desc= CFS - Mobile Student - %%b - %%a
echo.
echo Please enter Admin Username
set /p adminusr=
cls
echo.
echo Please enter Admin Password (make sure noone is looking as password is displayed)
set /p adminpw=
cls
echo.
echo Now creating local admin account for %%a on %%b
echo.
echo Description: !desc!
echo.
pause
***\psexec \\%LaptopID% -u ***\!adminusr! -p !adminpw! -n 20 -e net localgroup Administrators "***\%%a" /add
***\psexec \\%LaptopID% -u ***\!adminusr! -p !adminpw! -n 20 -e net config server /srvcomment:"!desc!"
pause
)
```

This should get you off the ground. I've no idea what you want to substitute for `***`.

Note that `@echo off` sets command-echoing off until an `echo on` is encountered. `@` before a command suppresses echoing of the individual command before it is executed.

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` sets a mode where a variable may be accessed in a block (parenthesised [multiline] statement sequence) by `!var!` to get the CURRENT value. `%var%` will get the value of the variable at the time the command invoking the block was PARSED - before execution.

You dont't say whether you want to apply the SAME admin a/c and password to EACH account created. The above should request both each time. The below should allow ONE entry and then apply it to EACH entry in your `.csv`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo.
echo The following script will assign a student to a laptop, giving the student
echo Administration rights to the laptop and set the laptop description.
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
cls
echo.
echo Please enter Admin Username
set /p adminusr=
cls
echo.
echo Please enter Admin Password (make sure noone is looking as password is displayed)
set /p adminpw=
cls
echo.
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%a in (data.csv) DO (
set user=%%a
set LaptopID=%%b
set desc= CFS - Mobile Student - %%b - %%a
echo Now creating local admin account for %%a on %%b
echo.
echo Description: !desc!
echo.
pause
***\psexec \\%LaptopID% -u ***\!adminusr! -p !adminpw! -n 20 -e net localgroup Administrators "***\%%a" /add
***\psexec \\%LaptopID% -u ***\!adminusr! -p !adminpw! -n 20 -e net config server /srvcomment:"!desc!"
pause
)
```

I'd strongly suggest you prefix `ECHO` you your ...psexec... lines temporarily to see what the resultant script would do before committing.

No idea of what you mean by `***`...

Comment: sorry the *** is just folder/server/region names here at the school. 

Yes sorry i did want to have the same username and pw for all the entries, however this code does not want to work. it seems that it is not picking up !adminusr! in psexec and it is refusing to give access to the pc.

Comment: also psexec does pop up and it shows you what it is doing so no echo required

Comment: ok i have used your edited code and i have been able to make it work the way i wanted it to! i will post the appropriate code tomorrow when i get to work (already very late going home because of this lol) thanks heaps